# Drawing a point in the exact position of a mouse click using Qt

Tags: qt, mouseevent, qpainter

I'm working on a Qt project. A point must be drawn on a mouse click on a Qpainter area. The point position is supposed to be on the same exact position of the mouse click, but for some reason the point is drawn in another position diagonal to the expected position.

The code :

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent)
: QMainWindow(parent), ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
QGraphicsView * view = new QGraphicsView(this) ;
ui->setupUi(this);
QGridLayout * gridLayout = new QGridLayout(ui->centralWidget);
gridLayout->addWidget(view);

scene = new QGraphicsScene();
scene->setSceneRect(50, 50, 350, 350);

view->setScene(scene);
} 

void MainWindow::mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent * e)
{
 QGraphicsView * view = new QGraphicsView(this) ;
 double rad = 1;
 QPointF pt = view->mapToScene(e->pos());
 scene->addEllipse(pt.x()-rad, pt.y()-rad, rad*2.0, rad*2.0,QPen(),  QBrush(Qt::SolidPattern));
}
```

Comment: So what with my answer? Did you try it, is it work as you want. I didn't get any feedback.

Comment: Sorry I stopped working on this project for a while, because I need to submit another project. As soon as possible I will try your code .

Answer (score 2):

Your code is not correct. You create heavy view every clicking, you should not do this. If you want that user will be able to interact with scene, then create new custom scene and do all hat you need in scene.

```
#ifndef GRAPHICSSCENE_H
#define GRAPHICSSCENE_H

#include <QGraphicsScene>
#include <QPoint>
#include <QMouseEvent>
class GraphicsScene : public QGraphicsScene
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit GraphicsScene(QObject *parent = 0);
    ~GraphicsScene();

signals:

protected:
    void mousePressEvent(QGraphicsSceneMouseEvent *event);
public slots:
    private:

};

#endif // GRAPHICSSCENE_H
```

cpp:

```
#include "graphicsscene.h"
#include <QDebug>

GraphicsScene::GraphicsScene(QObject *parent) :
    QGraphicsScene(parent)
{
}

GraphicsScene::~GraphicsScene()
{
    qDebug() << "deleted scene";
}


void GraphicsScene::mousePressEvent(QGraphicsSceneMouseEvent *mouseEvent)
{

      if (mouseEvent->button() == Qt::LeftButton)
      {
          double rad = 1;
          QPointF pt = mouseEvent->scenePos();
          this->addEllipse(pt.x()-rad, pt.y()-rad, rad*2.0, rad*2.0,QPen(),
          QBrush(Qt::SolidPattern));
      }

    QGraphicsScene::mousePressEvent(mouseEvent);
}
```

Usage, for example:

```
#include "graphicsscene.h"
//...
GraphicsScene *scene = new GraphicsScene(this);
someview->setScene(scene);
```

Comment: Thank you, I tried this code it worked but I still hava the same problem. The point position is supposed to be on the same exact position of the mouse click.

Comment: @shahdewai do you want draw point on scene or on whole mainWindow? This code should draw point where user clicks on scene.

Comment: I want it on the scene.

Comment: @shahdewai I don't see problem here, in my computer it works fine(center of ellipse is point where user clicked), edit your question and show full code.

Comment: Which version of Qt do have ?

Comment: @shahdewai Qt 5.2.0 and I run this code with `ui->graphicsView->setSceneRect(0,0,50,50);` to avoid auto-scrolling when I click and add item to scene.